# Loading/Navigating Pages Dynamically (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a recipe app, I have different categories that I want to dynamically load on click. To pull recipes I have a url (http get request) which I want to extend with a string depending on what category i click on.

The base url would be

`http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=/////&_app_key=/////`

On the end I would want to add either one of these.

`396^Dairy-Free`
`393^Gluten-Free`
`391^Nut-Free`
`393^Wheat-Free` and so on. Could someone please give me an idea on how to implement this

My HTML currently is

```
<ion-item [navPush] = "listingPage" detail-push>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <h1>Glueten Free</h1>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <h1>Category 2</h1>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <h1>Category 3</h1>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      <h1>Category 4</h1>
    </ion-item>
```

and HTTP request is

```
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=////&_app_key=//////')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        console.log(data);
        this.listing = data.matches;
        resolve(this.listing);
      });
  });
```

Currently I only have 1 url loading on a page, but I want this to change depending on what category selected. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you just wouldn't use an onClick handler and the Router to navigate? You can send whatever information you want as a sensible object or array instead of all that URL hacking.

For example, here is a simple header component I use as a base for most of my projects these days (Angular2):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// Make sure to import/inject Router
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

class HeaderComponent {
    // I use ES6, if you use TS just use the annotations.
    static get parameters ( ) {
        return [ Router ];
    }

    constructor ( router ) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    // Use in an ngFor to create a row of buttons
    get buttons ( ) {
        return [
            { label : 'Home', route : '/home' },
            { label : 'Notes', route : '/notes' },
            { label : 'About', route : '/about' }
        ]
    }

    // Used when you click the top right logo
    onImageClick ( ) {
        this.router.navigate ( [ '/home' ], { message : 12345 } );
    }

    // Used when a button is clicked
    onButtonClick ( data ) {
        this.router.navigate ( [ data.route ], { message : "whatever data you want" } );
    }
}

HeaderComponent.annotations = [
    new Component ( {
        selector : 'tcoz-header',
        templateUrl: './header.component.html',
        styleUrls: [ './header.component.css' ]
    } )
];

export { HeaderComponent }
```

Note that "message" is an arbitrary key name. It can be anything.

In the consuming view (the one being navigated to):

```
// Make sure to import/inject ActivatedRoute
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
// Get the incoming data via the "message" property in ngOnInit, etc.
let message = this.route.snapshot.params [ 'message' ];
```

Very easy this way, very readable (much more so IMHO than the somewhat cryptic :url_tokens etc.), particular when considering the transmission of data. If you need to transmit a complex object/array, just serialize the value of "message" (or whatever you call it) as JSON, then JSON.parse it on the receiving end.